# Show that the function $f: ((\mathbb{Z}, +) \rightarrow (\mathbb{C}, *)$ is a homomorphism of groups with $f(x) = i^x, \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, group-homomorphism

Given that $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ and $(\mathbb(C), *)$ are groups, show that the function $f: ((\mathbb{Z}, +) \rightarrow (\mathbb{C}, *)$ is a homomorphism of groups with $f(x) = i^x, \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Based on what I understand, I am to prove that:

- $f(x + y) = f(x) * f(y)$

From which I got:

$$
i^{(x+y)} = i^x * i^y \\
i^{(x+y)} = i^{(x+y)}
$$

- $f(e_\mathbb{Z}) = e_\mathbb{C}$ : $e$ - neutral element of the set.

From which I deduced that $e_\mathbb{Z} = 0$ therefore:

$$
f($e_\mathbb{Z}) = f_0 = i^0 = I = e_\mathbb{C}
$$

- $f(x^+) = f[(x)]^*$ where $x^+$ if the inverse of $x$.

Having that the inverse of a number for the addition in $\mathbb{Z}$ is it negative value, I have deduced that:

$$
f(-x) = (i^x)^* \\
i^{-x} = (i^x)^{-1} \\
i^{-x} = i^{-x}
$$

Would that last part be correct as it relates to the inverse of complex numbers?

Also how do I determine the kernel/nucleus of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $G$ is a group (written multiplicatively) and $g \in G$, then the map $f: \mathbb Z \to G$ given by $n \mapsto g^n$ is a homomorphism. It is the unique homomorphism $\mathbb Z \to G$ with $1 \mapsto g$.

The image of $f$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by $g$.

The kernel of $f$ is $m\mathbb Z$, where $m$ is the order of $g$, if $g$ has finite order, or $m=0$ if $g$ has infinite order.

In your example, $g=i \in \mathbb C$ has order $4$.

Comment: How did you obtain the order of $g$?

Comment: @OmariCelestine, that's the definition. Check your text. If you mean for $g=i$, just compute $i^1=i, i^2=-1, i^3=-i, i^4=1$.

Comment: But since both sets have an infinite number of elements, wouldn't the kernel also have an unlimited number?

Comment: @OmariCelestine, $4\mathbb Z$ is infinite.

Comment: $4\mathbb{Z}$? Where did the $4$ come from?